# IBM MobileFirst war file unable to deploy to MFP server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I had tried deploy both war file without java and jar files and with java and jar files. The war file without java and jar files managed to deploy successfully without any error in the log. The runtime appear in the admin console and everything works.

If I deploy server/java and jar war files, my runtime will disappear from the admin console. Here is my java lib,
I am using the IBM Server Configuration Tool to deploy war.

- axis.jar
- bcprov-jdk14-143.jar
- commons-discovery-0.2.jar
- commons=logging.jar
- CryptoPasswordTool_14.jar
- e2eejslib2048_b1.4_v1.3jar
- jaxrpc.jar
- jcprov.jar
- saaj.jar
- wsdl4j.jar
- xerces-2.9.1.jar

Here is my Java call

```
javax.xml.rpc.Service aacmService = javax.xml.rpc.ServiceFactory.newInstance().createService(new java.net.URL(connectionUrl),new javax.xml.namespace.QName(ssoLink, "SSOService"));
```

These library had been used in my server/java to make some customized server call.Is there any of these jar files that will crash with MFP?

In this environment, I unable to get to copy anything out from the server due to the client policy. But I managed to take a shot on the screen.
[image: Error Message in Server]

Comment: Giving screen shots as the log is not going to work. Find a way to provide the log or go ahead and open a PMR.

Answer (score 0):

Without proper information to review, such as the complete log file to see all errors printed, the recommendation is to open a PMR instead of a question on stack overflow, which anyway is more suitable for programming questions rather than infrastructure questions.

Open a support ticket to IBM: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21507643